# Как убрать отступ у select на android?

Tags: html, android, css

На андроиде у элемента  слева есть отступ в пару пикселей. Обнуление паддингов и марджинов не помогает, `text-indent: 0;` не помогает. Нашел похожую проблему на stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28504026/left-offset-of-select-text), чтобы было понятно о чем речь, но решения там нет. Может кто-нибудь знает как решить проблему или хотя бы включить вангу и предложить какие-то варианты? Гугление не помогает.

Comment: Опишите более детально что вы пытаетесь сделать, а то не понятно как именно вы пытаетесь показать html в Android. Это сайт или нативное приложение?

Comment: Это сайт, я использую Chrome Canary дня отладки.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте присвоить `padding`, `text-indent` и `margin` для тега `option`.
Если используется стандартный шрифт и он не подключён через CSS, попробуйте его подключить.

Comment: Применение стилей к option не помогает, шрифт используется не стандартный и уже подключен.

Comment: Используете свойства `-webkit-appearance`, `border-width`, `box-sizing`?

Comment: Не помогает. Свойства со значениями none, 0 и border-box соответственно не дают нужного результата. Пробовал применить и к option и к select.

Comment: Добавьте свойство  `margin-left: -3px;` к select и сделайте обнуление при min-width 768px.

Comment: Дело в том, что в IOS все нормально отображается, поэтому я и упомянул андроид.

Comment: Используйте js.
`var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1;
if(isAndroid) {
 jQuery("select").css({'margin-left':'-3px'});
}`

Comment: Как вариант, спасибо. Вообще печально, что проблема не исправляется на уровне стилей.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так убирается:

```
select {
    font: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    text-transform: inherit;
    text-shadow: inherit;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте свойство `margin-left: -3px;` к `select`, это работает.
Кому нужно убрать отступ в `select`.

Comment: Последнее предложение не понятно. Что вы имели ввиду?